# How to move ActiveAdmin.register_page to a gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, activeadmin

I would like to move some of the code from `app/admin` folder to an external gem.

I've tried it several times and not very successfully — page in ActiveAdmin doesn't show up.

Can someone point me in some direction?

Comment: could you be more specific? What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried to create gem with engine, and to create `app/admin` folder inside of it, and to create file `page.rb` with all default code for activeadmin page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, found a solution.

To add your custom pages to `activeadmin` inside your gem, you need to use `ActiveAdmin.before_load` with `load_paths` attribute.

```
module Test
  class Engine < Rails::Engine
    initializer "active_admin" do |app|
      ActiveAdmin.before_load do |app|
        app.load_paths << File.expand_path("../../../app/admin", __FILE__)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you gem file structure should probabily look someting like

```
your_gem
└── lib
    ├── admin
    │   └── some_model.rb
    └── your_gem.rb
```

and the file `your_gem.rb` should contain `require 'admin/some_model'`

Comment: I think, if I am using engine inside of the gem, then I can use a default structure for rails apps, like 'app/...'. Tested multiple times.

Comment: I don't see any advantage in using an engine here. You're just trying to move a few files outside of your application. As long as the file calls `ActiveAdmin.register` and gets loaded, should work fine.

Comment: The engine gives a lot of advantages and one of them most valuable is the ability to move assets to the gem also. You can keep all of the needed files in one place.

Comment: sure, you can still use an engine and keep this structure. I'm not sure of what's the effect of adding a folder inside the app folder in an engine. It sounds reasonable but if it's not working for you, I would explicitely require those files.

Comment: Tried to manually require these files, but application throwed an error, that ActiveAdmin was missing. It seems that my require was run before ActiveAdmin.

Comment: have you added active_admin as a dependency in your gemspec?

Comment: If that doesn't work, you can also add require 'active_admin' before requiring the files. It's not a problem since ruby won't load the same file twice.